# How to put string into SICStus Prolog function as a variable and return it as the string?

Tags: prolog

I have tried with atom_chars function but it doesn't work. What get_string function should do is following:

- get string from JavaScript as a input variable,
- and return it as a string, that is all.

`get_string(in,out):- atom_chars(in,out).`

Comment: Look at the precise error message! It will help you!

Comment: The problem is, that I can't see the error because Prolog is calling as the plugin without error messages. With other words, the error I'm receiving is related to the system what I working with.

Comment: I do not think I understand what you want. Please edit your question to explain what get_string/2 should do, and some example calls. (The code above calls atom_chars/2 with two atoms, which will of course fail).

Answer (score 1):

The function get_string was for testing purpose.

```
get_string(X,Y):- copy_term(X,Y).
```

It works fine. Thank you for your time.